# Writing contents of bpy.data.texts to folder with bpy.ops.text.save

Tags: python, scripting

I am reading my scripts from a folder with:

```
import bpy
import pathlib
for file in pathlib.Path("C:\\awesome\\scripts\\folder").iterdir():
    bpy.ops.text.open(filepath = str(file))
```

Now i can use the scripts in blender itself and may change some stuff here and there. To save a script as a user i can use **Alt + S**. For scripting this procedure, blender shows a tooltip with **bpy.ops.text.save()** but i don't know how to define which text i want to save. I guess it will be something like:

```
import bpy
for text in bpy.data.texts:
    bpy.data.texts.active = text
    bpy.ops.text.save()
```

But **bpy.data.texts.active** is actually not available.

TL;DR: Where to define the active text?

Best,
Mamu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find current active text object in `screen.areas` of text editor

```
area = next(area for area in context.screen.areas if area.type == 'TEXT_EDITOR')
text_obj = area.spaces.active.text
```

Assume that you know your text-block name, then assign that text type to active text:

```
area.spaces.active.text = bpy.data.texts['Text.001']
```

This will change the current active text object.

Answer (score 2):

**Without Operators**

Both the reading and writing can be done without operators.

```
import bpy
import pathlib
for file in pathlib.Path("somefolder").iterdir():
    text = bpy.data.texts.load(str(file))
```

and writing

```
import bpy
from pathlib import Path

for text in bpy.data.texts:
    # internal
    if text.is_in_memory:
        continue
    path = Path(bpy.path.abspath(text.filepath))
    if path.exists():
        path.write_text(text.as_string())
```